# Open PDF Full Window Size In The Same Tab - Web Dev

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, web

I'm new to web development and I want to open a PDF at full window size in the current browser tab.
I tried using an HTML `object` with as `data` my PDF path. Then in CSS I said `width:100%; height:100%;`.
This ends up showing only the width at 100% and a much smaller height, how can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        embed {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);">PDF</a>
</body>
    <script>
        function launchFullscreen(element) {         
            if (element.requestFullscreen) {
                element.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                element.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
                element.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            document.body.style.height = "100vh";
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
            document.body.innerHTML = '<embed src="sys.pdf" />';
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

To open something in current tab you can use target attribute of an anchor tag, for example:

```
<a href="name.pdf" target="_self">PDF</a>
```

To force the browser open page in fullscreen mode, you can use Fullscreen API, described in following article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

The examples of code and some demos you can find here: https://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen

**Update:**

Check the code snippet. You need just change `src` attribute value of the `embed` tag on 30th line to your pdf path.

**Update2:**

To resize browser window you can call risezeTo() function. But, there are several limitations on it, described there (with examples): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo .

Simply put: resizing the window, even if one tab is open in the browser - not allowed in all browsers. In some browsers you can do that only if the current tab is the only one. In other you can`t do even that. But, you can open a new window using window.open() with particular width and height, and load your pdf file inside it. Documentation and examples are there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but that's not what I'm looking for: your code opens the PDF in a new tab and not in the same tab, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I think you misunderstood: I didn't want to open the document in full screen, but in full browser window size, sorry for making you wait

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood. :) I`ve updated the post, please check it out.

Comment: Sorry, I must have used the wrong words, I'll try to explain it better: when I click a link in the website I want to open the pdf in that same tab, and I want the pdf to fill the entire web page

Comment: If so, you can just use <a href="name.pdf" target="_self">PDF</a>, where href equals to your pdf path, and target="_self" means that link will be opened in the same tab.

Comment: Yup, but it isn't in full window size

Comment: Can you share the screenshot? :)

Comment: Don't worry, I think it's actually better to open the pdf in another tab, thank again!